# Why is this python code producing extremely large numbers?

Tags: python, loops, random, iteration

I have a python code which is the written below. What is disturbing to me is the large number that I am getting as output in the array `rhot`. This can't be true as `val` is mostly small number and these small numbers are further suppressed by the exponential factor as in the line

```
 rhot[i, j, k] = (rhot[i, j, k] + val[j, k, l] *
                                     np.exp(-(vlist[i] - velz[j, k, l]) ** 2 / (2 * beta)))
```

Does any one know why I am getting large numbers as output for `rhot`?

```
import numpy as np
import random

n = 6
val = np.empty((n, n, n))  #  produces n*n*n empty matrix
for i in range(0, n - 1):
    for j in range(0, n - 1):
        for k in range(0, n - 1):
            val[i, j, k] = random.lognormvariate(0, 1) 
# produces lognormal random numbers with mean 1 and standard deviation 1
velz = np.empty((n, n, n))
for i in range(0, n - 1):
    for j in range(0, n - 1):
        for k in range(0, n - 1):
            velz[i, j, k] = random.normalvariate(0, 1)
# produces normal random numbers with mean 1 and standard deviation 1
vmax = np.amax(velz)  # maximum of flat velz array
vmin = np.amin(velz)  # minimum
vlist = np.linspace(vmin, vmax, n)
# print(velz)
# print(val)
# print (vlist)
beta = 0.2  
rhot = np.empty((n, n, n))
for i in range(0, n - 1):  # index of velocity
    for j in range(0, n - 1):
        for k in range(0, n - 1):
            for l in range(0, n - 1):  # z index
                rhot[i, j, k] = (rhot[i, j, k] + val[j, k, l] *
                                 np.exp(-(vlist[i] - velz[j, k, l]) ** 2 / (2 * beta)))  # sums over 3rd dimension l, and stores the sum.
print(rhot)
```

Comment: Why don't you investigate this by yourself? Just print every term when a big value pops out and keep tracking...

Comment: I did, and it is the last line where rhot[i, j, k] comes first that is causing large numbers to arise. But, this term should clearly not give any large numbers because of the exponential supressing factor (negative term inside the exponential should indeed make exponential always less than 1).

Comment: Well as I said if it 'should' but doesn't, then check any intermediate results...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could be wrong, but when I run your code I get small values. Could it be that you're seeing things like `-3.53107108e-310` and confusing them for large numbers? 
That's:

```
-0.0 ... <307 '0's> ... 0353107108
```

See below for the full output:

```
[[[  1.27490729e+000   2.48048100e+000   3.07058432e+000   7.30862963e-001
     3.61289051e-002   0.00000000e+000]
  [  1.29285884e+000   9.53558990e-001   1.16462089e+000   6.18595057e-001
     4.56208365e-001   0.00000000e+000]
  [  3.48843064e-002   3.51048158e-001   6.72572870e-001   1.44242671e-004
     1.08715529e-002   0.00000000e+000]
  [  1.34866696e+000   3.61798504e-002   4.94111513e-001   1.67366765e-001
     1.45956417e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  2.11027716e+000   1.15784556e+000   6.16183788e-002   1.58361518e-001
     5.75876010e-001   0.00000000e+000]
  [  0.00000000e+000  -2.22731705e-310   7.48734566e-315   7.48735151e-315
     8.63509807e-312   0.00000000e+000]]

 [[  8.71788238e-001   8.75201841e+000   4.64974371e+000   2.59647886e+000
     1.16994333e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  1.19599140e+000   8.74687167e-001   2.50158015e+000   2.75257757e+000
     9.92597288e-001   0.00000000e+000]
  [  1.84015219e+000   1.12041236e+000   3.52262073e-001   1.49498067e-001
     7.51724231e-001   0.00000000e+000]
  [  5.34739555e+000   2.75435540e+000   1.61068778e+001   1.59134588e+000
     9.67835496e-001   0.00000000e+000]
  [  2.76116504e+000   2.03916401e+000   1.90723731e-001   2.82388640e+000
     3.04602826e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  0.00000000e+000  -2.55325566e-310   7.48734566e-315   7.48735293e-315
     8.63509811e-312   0.00000000e+000]]

 [[  5.24104854e+000   9.34017262e+000   4.00934108e+000   3.83152870e+000
     1.62852403e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  3.32402433e-001   5.13142568e-001   1.56460377e+000   3.98199095e+000
     3.10752863e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  7.32201046e+000   4.60614519e+000   6.65947236e-001   3.50609348e+000
     2.43255192e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  1.20735878e+001   1.43430640e+001   1.13987763e+001   2.33564499e+000
     4.11797274e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  4.56305322e+000   2.19230864e+000   2.04935419e+000   5.93349070e+000
     1.34685870e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  0.00000000e+000  -2.87919425e-310   7.48734566e-315   7.48735435e-315
     8.63509811e-312   0.00000000e+000]]

 [[  2.00871165e+000   1.07657987e+001   1.73466587e+000   5.37829126e+000
     1.67186888e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  7.04409708e-001   9.18488325e-001   5.65912359e+000   3.07782156e+000
     1.90251174e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  2.61090422e+000   1.76056043e+000   4.02183805e+000   5.16605380e+000
     2.54000338e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  5.83011318e+000   3.84800152e+000   1.52000638e+000   2.67037387e+000
     3.79550774e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  4.66619590e-001   4.10817751e+000   5.59173904e+000   1.44794224e+000
     3.69302488e-001   0.00000000e+000]
  [  0.00000000e+000  -3.20513286e-310   7.48734566e-315   7.48734803e-315
     8.63509813e-312   0.00000000e+000]]

 [[  1.79494277e-002   3.42477445e-001   1.69493310e-002   4.18988338e-001
     2.47334739e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  1.06263981e-001   3.27704176e-001   6.35008094e-001   1.01981741e-001
     8.65984592e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  1.19169164e-001   1.93839020e-001   1.63208875e+000   1.34924978e+000
     2.13064890e+000   0.00000000e+000]
  [  7.85718993e-001   4.96021083e+000   3.80732389e-001   3.45316057e+000
     2.54260569e-001   4.11408160e-304]
  [  3.11511258e-003   3.52866964e-001   2.00264974e+000   2.47368641e-002
     6.53491661e-001   3.70335798e-318]
  [  0.00000000e+000  -3.53107108e-310   7.48734328e-315   7.48734249e-315
     8.63509820e-312   0.00000000e+000]]

 [[  0.00000000e+000  -3.58539416e-310   7.48734407e-315   7.48734234e-315
     8.63509829e-312   0.00000000e+000]
  [  0.00000000e+000  -3.63971726e-310   7.48734313e-315   7.48734866e-315
     8.63509783e-312   0.00000000e+000]
  [  0.00000000e+000  -3.69404039e-310   7.48734392e-315   7.48734265e-315
     8.63509828e-312   0.00000000e+000]
  [  0.00000000e+000  -3.74836347e-310   7.48734360e-315   7.48734249e-315
     8.63509814e-312   0.00000000e+000]
  [  0.00000000e+000  -3.80268659e-310   7.48734439e-315   7.48734234e-315
     8.63509327e-312   0.00000000e+000]
  [  0.00000000e+000  -3.85700970e-310   7.48734392e-315   7.48734249e-315
     8.63509814e-312   0.00000000e+000]]]
```